# Help using eigenvectors to solve Markov chain

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains, steady-state

I took Linear Algebra last semester and when learning about Markov Chains in my statistics class, I wanted to use eigenvectors/eigenvalues to find the steady-state vector rather than just using systems of equations like our professor taught us. I seem to be having a bit of trouble, however. Here's an example:

Let's say we have a transition matrix P:

$$
    P = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
    0.5 & 0 & 0.5 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

We know that one of the eigenvalues is 1, since it is a Markov chain. The other eigenvalues can be found via $det(P - \lambda I)$:

$$
    \lambda_1 = 1
$$
$$
    \lambda_2 = -0.5
$$

Thus making the eigenvectors:

$$
    x_1 = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
    x_2 = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -0.5 \\
    -0.5 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

This is where I always get stuck. In another example, I simply normalized $x_1$ to get 
$$
    x_{ss} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{3} \\
    \frac{1}{3} \\
    \frac{1}{3} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

for the long-term forecast/steady state vector. For this example however, a calculator revealed that the steady state vector was actually
$$
    x_{ss} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{4}{9} \\
    \frac{2}{9} \\
    \frac{3}{9} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

How do I get there from the eigenvectors? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve found *right* eigenvectors of $P$, but what you really need are the *left* eigenvectors: you’re trying to solve $\pi P=\pi$, not $P\pi=\pi$. Use whatever technique you used to compute the eigenvectors of $P$ on $P^T$ instead.

Incidentally, since the rows of a row-stochastic matrix all sum to $1$, the vector consisting of all $1$s will always be a right eigenvector.

Comment: Thank you so so much!! This was the key!